# how to create new drupal-wall node through custom module?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I have using drupal wall contributed module to posting purpose,and these posts create through custom module, i have used node_save() to create a new nodes.

but problem is instead of user/author name  Anonymous (not verified) shown in posting page.

```
$node = new stdClass ();
$node->type = 'drupal_wall';
node_object_prepare ($node);
$node->uid = 10;             
$node->name = "Your node title";
$node->language = 'und';
$node->comment = 2;
$node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'hello'; 
$node = node_submit($node); 
node_save($node);
```

i want user name displayed instead of  Anonymous (not verified) . any ideas???

Comment: On a quick glance the code is OK; are you sure that the user with ID 10 exists on the site?

Comment: yes exists, same code tried 'article' content type it working fine,but tried with drupal_wall not working.

Comment: well  $node->name will get you the name of the author who submitted the node. It will return it as string, not as link to the user account.

Comment: Try with `$node->title` instead of `$node->name`.

Comment: @Abin is correct, you should use `$node->title` instead of `$node->name` to set the node title.

Comment: guys i tried with $node->title instead of $node->name in article type it works but drupal_wall not working, got appache shoutdown.